# How to encrypt a file which is on a server

Tags: linux, command-line, openssl

For encryption i am using `openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in abc.txt -out abc.txt.enc`so now how to encrypt a file from my desktop where the file is in server like \10.113.123.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSH access to the host:

```
$ ssh username@server openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in abc.txt -out abc.txt.enc
```

This will connect to the host `server` as `username` and run the specified command.

The `openssl` command will write to standard output if no output file is specified, which means you may store the result in a local file with

```
$ ssh username@server openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in abc.txt >abc.txt.enc
```

Comment: if the file is in a directory how to give path

Comment: @prasanna Just specify the path on the command line, either as an absolute path (`/some/path/abc.txt`) or relative from you home directory on the server (`some/path/abc.txt`).  The same goes for the output file.

Comment: and one more thing is i want to save the encrypted file in my system but not in remote system is it possible ?

Comment: what command would you use to decrypt this file?

Comment: openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -in abc.txt .enc -out abc.txt

Comment: @prasanna that doesn't work for me. I get error `bad magic number`

Comment: ur using aescrypt or open ssl? @the_velour_fog

Comment: @prasanna just the command you gave

Comment: just use "openssl  aes-256-cbc -d -a  -in abc.txt.enc -out abc.txt.new"

Comment: and one more thing is i want to save the encrypted file directly in my system but not in remote system is it possible ?@Kusalananda

Comment: @prasanna See updated answer.

Comment: Yes it is working and small doubt what if i am using aescrypt "aescrypt -e -p passkey abc.txt" for encryption and the encrypted file should be saved directly in local system

Comment: @prasanna You keep asking new questions in this comment thread. It would be better if you asked your questions on the main site where other may see them. For this last question, if you can make `aescrypt` (a command I don't have access to) write to standard output ( the terminal), then you may redirect it to a local file, just as with the `openssl` command.

Comment: i don't have reputation to create new tag as aescrypt so ...

Comment: @prasanna But you can ask new questions, and there's an "encryption" tag.

Comment: The encrypted file has been created but it is zero size in local system @Kusalananda

Comment: @prasanna With `openssl`, I can not reproduce the zero-size issue on my system.